# How to avoid keep double clicking continuously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
$('#element').dblclick(function(e){  
    console.log("event");
});
```

When I click the element at a very fast click, it shows the event many times. But I want the user prevent double clicking continuously, maybe skip it for 1 second, how can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

```
var click_allowed = true;
$('#element').dblclick(function(e){ 
  if (!click_allowed) return;
  console.log("event");
  click_allowed = false; 
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    click_allowed = true;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `true` and `false` MUST be written in lowercase. You'll get a reference error otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to ensure that your event handler runs only once, and then you can rebind it once enough time has elapsed ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxrtp/)):

```
function dblclickHandler(e){  
    console.log("event");
    setTimeout(setHandler, 1000);
}

function setHandler() {
    $('#element').one('dblclick', dblclickHandler);
}

setHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [doTimeout plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/), specifically the debounce feature: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/debouncing/. Try the first example on the second link I posted. Then, just modify it for double clicking instead of `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastClick = 0;
$('#element').dblclick(function(e){ 
  var time = (new Date()).getTime();
  if(time > lastClick + 1000) {
    lastClick = time;
    console.log("event");
  }
}
```